# Change Smartsupp Chat position dynamically

Tags: position, chat, smartsupp

I installed a Smartsupp chat on my site, fully functional, added at the bottom right of the page; I then inserted a sticky shopping cart when the static cart is passed, but it is positioned under the chat, thus compromising the functions of the cart

As the documentation says, I edited via the configuration script with the code

```
_smartsupp.offsetY = X;
```

and it works, but the location is not changed dynamically;

To explain myself better, it is positioned in the correct position only when the page is reloaded and then regenerated the button, not while the page scrolls and the sticky cart appears, as I would like.

Does anyone know if it is possible to make it move dynamically as I would like or once it is generated its position remains fixed? Thank you so much!